# jQuery overwriting 'this' in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have declared a JavaScript object:

```
function A(name){
    this.name=name
}

A.prototype.test=function(){
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

as a simple example I have set up a button that if it's clicked should output a variable to the local console log:

```
<button id='test'>test</button>
```

the script:

```
var t=new A('hello');
$('#test').click(t.test);
```

when I click the button I want `this.name` to show (in this case 'hello'), but instead `this` refers to the clicked button, and not to the object I created.

this is a debugging script of course. In real life I'm binding a function to the window.resize event which will re-build a window on resizing.

There is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n9bqk65/) that shows the problem.

I have one solution for this, that is declaring the resize (or click function) in the constructor of the object and using an alternative name for `this`, like so ([Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n9bqk65/1/)):

```
function A(name){
    this.name=name

    var self=this;
    $("#test").click(function(){
        console.log(self.name);
    });
}
```

but I'd rather use a prototype and bind the function in the object's constructor. How can I do this using prototypes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), which will set the value of `this` ahead of time:

```
var t=new A('hello');
$('#test').click(t.test.bind(t));
```

Comment: Thanks! This can even be called from within the object constructor: $("#test").click(this.test.bind(this)); Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @patrick What you just said doesn't make a lot of sense. That call is making sure that the `test` function is called with `t` as its `this` value. It's similar (not exactly the same) to calling `$('#test').click(function() { t.test() };`

Comment: Juan, you're right, I tested the function and it worked like a charm!